# Why won't PySimpleGui.Input adjust the height correctly?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I am trying to create a simple input form for data entry, but I can't get the text input box to change the height, only the width changes when setting the size parameter.

Here is my code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def main():
    # # create small form for Data Analysis entry
 
    last_printer = sg.Input(key = 'last_printer', size = (10,1))
    rejected_carts = sg.Input(key = 'rejected_carts', size = (20, 1))
    notes_for_self = sg.Input(key = 'notes_for_self', size = (50,4))
    notes_for_ops = sg.Input(key = 'notes_for_ops', size = (50, 4))
    notes_for_escalation = sg.Input(key = 'notes_for_escalation', size =(50,4))

    layout = [        
        [sg.Text("Last Printer:"), last_printer],
        [sg.Text("Rejected Cartridges:"), rejected_carts],
        [sg.Text("Notes for Self:"), notes_for_self],
        [sg.Text("Notes for Operators:"), notes_for_ops],
        [sg.Text("Notes for Escalation:"), notes_for_escalation],
        [sg.Submit(), sg.Cancel()]
        ]   

    window = sg.Window("Data Analysis Entry Form", layout) #, finalize=True, keep_on_top=True, grab_anywhere=False, size = (1220, 600))

    event, values = window.read()
    
    window.close()

    print("event is: " + event)
    
    for each in values.items():
        print(each)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `PySimpleGUI.Input` element is same as `tkinter.Entry`. There's no option for height, so option `size[1]` is not used, just for consistency. The height of Input or Entry is always 1. For multiline, you can use `PySimpleGUI.Multiline`.

Comment: Thank you Jason, that makes perfect sense. I wish PySimpleGUI's website and call reference would make that clear. I was trying to find the tkinter call reference but I don't see a definitive place, just a lot of universities that have published their own guides.

Answer (score 0):

```
last_printer = sg.Multiline(key = 'last_printer', size = (10,1))
rejected_carts = sg.Multiline(key = 'rejected_carts', size = (20, 1))
notes_for_self = sg.Multiline(key = 'notes_for_self', size = (50,4))
notes_for_ops = sg.Multiline(key = 'notes_for_ops', size = (50, 4))
```